# python package or executable file

Tags: python, module, package

I have many python modules for my project. And I need to put those all on the server so that they will automatically run every week.

so now I am thinking about how I can move all those modules to the server. Should I package it up or should I make them into the exe file to be installed?. I do not make the GUI so I think might exe is not a good choice. but I am open to all suggestion because now I do not know exactly what I should do.

Comment: I would make a zip app. take a look at the corresponding python standard modules

Comment: thank you for your suggestion